# Maximum width that won't cause horizontal scroll bar at 1024x768 resolution

Tags: screen-resolution

What is the maximum possible width that won't cause horizontal scroll bar when the monitor resolution is 1024x768 ?

I tested my self and found out that 1008px but i want to be sure. I want to design the website with maximum possible width that won't cause any horizontal scroll bar at the desktop computers browser and when the resolution is 1024x768px

Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my experience, I would recommend you to set the max width between 980 and 1000 px... It feels nice when the website shows a bit of background on the side(s). But, 1008, as you measured it, it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

Common advice is that for the 1024 resolutions you have a maximum width of around 960 or 980px to work with. **But if you really need to get every last pixel in, I can confirm test results from Windows XP running at 1024×768, with Internet Explorer 6.0 fully maximized, gives you a width of 1007px to work with.**

ref: http://philfreo.com/blog/largest-website-width-to-support-1024x768-resolution/